# How can use updated/ new AMI in autoscaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have running a server (server-01) with elastic IP, it become unresponsive sometimes due to high CPU and memory usage.
I would like to use Auto Scaling here, but I have some doubts.

Suppose,

1. I have taken the AMI named (AMI-1) of current running server (server-01).
2. Created Launch Configuration LC-1 with AMI-1, used same subnet, key-pair, security group, instance type of server-01.
3. Created Auto-scaling group ASG-1 with launch configuration LC-1, It will contain:
   desired capacity - 1
   minimum capacity - 1
   maximum capacity - 3.

I will use CPU matrix, if cpu goes above 80% then launch new server.

If I created the Launch Configuration today, and cpu usage/problem will occur in next 30 days. So lots of changes/update will be there in application code in this 30 days time period.

But Auto-scaling will launch the new servers with old AMI (AMI-1), which is used in Launch Configuration LC-1.

Is there any way to use new updated AMI in auto scaling group each time,and also update the Elastic IP?

Can anyone help me out please, what will be the best practice to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to use new updated AMI in auto scaling group each time

You can use [instance refresh](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-instance-refresh-for-ec2-auto-scaling/) for your ASG. With a bit of work, you can **automate** full process, which is also explained in the AWS blog titled [Introducing Instance Refresh for EC2 Auto Scaling](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-instance-refresh-for-ec2-auto-scaling/)

> update the Elastic IP

Since you are using ASG with max capacity of 3, the use of **EIP does not make much sense**. Instead, you should use [load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/?elb-whats-new.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&elb-whats-new.sort-order=desc) which would be an entry point for your application. If you really require **static public IP** for your application, then you should use either Application LB with global accelerator or Network LB.

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
Create New Launch Configuration LC-2  with your desired new AMI Id.
and assign it to Auto Scaling Group.
```

You can't edit AMI once you created Launch Configuration LC-1 ( You can't change anything once you create Launch configuration).

Next Time when Auto Scaling Event happens (when your cloudwatch triggers) it will select new LC-2 and will launch new instance with your desired newly added AMI

Comment: Okay, but it's difficult to create a new Launch configuration all time and then update the auto scaling group with new Launch Configuration. Is there any way to automate all things, like to create Launch Configuration with new AMI and update the Auto scaling group. So any piece of code should not left anytime.

Comment: you can use cloudFormation to Automate these all, but still you need to mention new AMI id manually in that